# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Entity vs Args

Tags: c#, oop, frameworks, entity

If I check the equalities of two datas with first if statement when `ent.column` is empty there will be error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I check the equalities of two datas with second if statement and `args.column` is null, everything is works fine. Sorry for bad explain, this one is my first on stackoverflow.

```
myTable ent;//this comes from db;
myclass args// this comes from view;

//gives error
if(ent.column.Equals(args.column)){
  //some code         
}

//successfully check 
if(args.column.Equals(ent.column)){ 
  //some code         
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: _"When I check the equalities of two datas with second if statement and args.column is null, everything is works fine."_ Then you are looking wrong. You cannot call `Equals` on `null`. If this is a typo and you meant that in the second if it works if **ent** .column is null then that would be expected. Because you can check equality with `null`.

Comment: In your first if statement is ent null or is column null? If ent is null you'll get a null reference exception from trying to access column. If column is null, you'll get a null reference exception from tryin gto call `Equals` on it

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
myObject.NonNullProperty.Equals(null); // works ...
```

... because a) I can call Equals on that property (which is not null) and b) Equals accepts `null` without throwing an exception.

```
myObject.NullProperty.Equals(anotherObject); // fails ...
```

... because (given `NullProperty` is `null`) you cannot call an instance method (here: "Equals") if there is no instance of any object.

Possible workaround:

```
if( myObject.MayBeNullProp != null && // stops evaluating here if false
    theOtherObject.MayBeNullProp != null && // stops evaluating here if false
    myObject.MayBeNullProp.Equals(theOtherObject.MayBeNullProp) ) 
{
   // Executed if both are != null and equal
}
```